# Compute area of a sphere through a Dirac delta

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, geometric-measure-theory

I've been having issues with integrating with a Dirac delta. To compute the area of a sphere centered at $(0,0,0)$ it seems to work just fine:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\delta(r-\rho)r^2\sin\theta\, dr}\,d\theta}\,d\phi} = 4\pi\rho^2$$

Now I will take the same sphere but offset by $(0,0,\rho)$, that is: $x^2 + y^2 + (z-\rho)^2 = \rho^2$. Going to spherical coordinates yields: $r^2\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta + r^2\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta + (r\cos\theta-\rho)^2 = \rho^2$, which yields: $r(r-2\rho\cos\theta)=0$, and we can express the sphere in spherical coordinates as: $r(\theta) = 2\rho\cos\theta, \theta \in [0,\pi/2], \phi\in[0,2\pi]$.
Integrating yields:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\delta(r-2\rho\cos\theta)r^2\sin\theta\, dr}\,d\theta}\,d\phi} = \frac{8\pi\rho^2}{3}$$

Now this is not right clearly. The only reason I can think of has to do something with properties of the Dirac  delta I am unaware of. Note that I have not studied measure theory. I need the Dirac delta and not a surface integral  because I will be using this to compute transformations of probability density functions which I will need to write through a Dirac delta.

Edit: References covering this for engineers/computer science students are welcome.

Edit 2:
Taking into account David Holden's answer I came up with the following fact which must hold (I hope it's correct):
$$\int_{V}{\delta(f(x)) \,dx} = \int_{S = \{x|f(x) =0\}}{\,dA}$$

Edit 3:
I found some more information on the subject:
[Impulse functions over curves and surfaces](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022247X05006906/1-s2.0-S0022247X05006906-main.pdf?_tid=c03a1654-0e9c-473b-844e-98be18ddb831&acdnat=1548289589_5b46c07e684da2e6d49c3ccf08bc6847)
[Properties_in_n_dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties_in_n_dimensions)
[Surface area from indicator function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739777/surface-area-from-indicator-function)
[Property of Dirac delta function in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56939/property-of-dirac-delta-function-in-mathbbrn)
[Does the coarea formula hold for delta-function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134926/does-the-coarea-formula-hold-for-delta-function)

I believe the issue was that whenever I offset the sphere the Dirac delta changed such that $\delta(f(r)) \rightarrow \delta(g(r,\theta))$ and $g$ was then a non-trivial mapping (so it's not the one-dimensional dirac delta I am used to anymore). Based on the first article I believe that I can rewrite it as a surface Dirac delta $\delta(g(r,\theta)) = \delta_S(r,\theta)$ which yields the surface integral giving a correct result. The other threads and wikipedia state that I should have a normalization by the magnitude of the gradient. I think I am missing an important piece since for the result to be correct this normalization factor should cancel out with something. More precisely:
$$\int_V{\delta(r-2\rho\cos\theta)r^2\sin\theta \,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi} = \int_S{\frac{\,d\sigma}{\sqrt{r^2+\rho^2-2r\rho\cos\theta}}}$$
The only idea I have is that somehow the normalization factor will pop out of the $\,d\sigma$. No idea though since it's supposed to be a 'Minkowski content measure' which is way over my head as a computer science student.

To add to this I would also like to be able to solve the same problem with a heaviside function (for integrating the volume of the offset ball). I am unsure whether similar considerations apply there, however if I integrate it, the result seems correct. I still want to make sure this is valid for other volumes also (maybe it's just a coincidence like the sphere centered at $(0,0,0)$). So I would be grateful if somebody with more knowledge on geometric measure theory could clarify all of the points.

Comment: @Bernard I can't understand what was edited in the integrals. Can you elaborate for future reference?

Comment: Dirac is a surname, so it has an initial capital. Also I added unbreakable thin spaces ( code: `\,`) in front of the differentials.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864255/surface-area-of-sphere-using-dirac-delta

Comment: $8 \pi \rho^2/3$ is the correct value for the given integral, it's just a consequence of $\int_{\mathbb R} \delta(x - a) \phi(x) dx = \phi(a)$. However, the correct relation between the volume and the surface integrals is
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(f(\mathbf x)) \,|\nabla f(\mathbf x)| \,d\mathbf x =
\int_{f(\mathbf x) = 0} dA.$$

Comment: @Maxim It's not the correct value since I've implicitly dealt with a composition of a delta function with a submersion as if it were a the one dimensional delta function, which is incorrect.

Comment: With the standard definition of $\delta(f)$, the first two integrals can be evaluated simply as iterated integrals (in any order), the second one giving $8 \pi \rho^2/3$, while the formulas in Edit 2 and Edit 3 are incorrect. You can introduce some other definition and work with some other functional $\delta_f$, but I believe the issue is that you'll end up with different change of variables formulas for regular and singular functionals. Also, if you write $\int_V$, first you have to assign a meaning to $\int_0^\infty \delta(x) dx$.

Comment: @Maxim The point is that they cannot. Namely this step is incorrect: $\int_V{\delta(r-2\rho\cos\theta)r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi} = \int_S{4\rho^2\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi}$. It is inconsistent with the definition of the Dirac delta (as you will notice from the linked references). $\delta$ already has a well-defined meaning as the limit of normal distributions, I don't think I can change that.

Comment: I don't know what normal distributions are and why you would need to define the delta function as a limit. Also not sure what you mean by $\int_S d\theta d\phi$. If it's a surface integral over the sphere, then the equality doesn't hold. If it's a double integral over the rectangle in the $(\theta, \phi)$ plane, the equality holds. Your formula in Edit 2 would imply $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(2 f(\mathbf x)) d\mathbf x = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(f(\mathbf x)) d\mathbf x$, which doesn't obey the change of variables rule.

Comment: @Maxim The normal distribution is also known as the Gaussian distribution, check the definition of the Dirac delta for further details. I  didn't get what you found wrong with my derivation in edit 3. It is an application of $\int_{R^n}{\delta(g(x))dx} = \int_{g^{-1}(0)}{\frac{\,d\sigma}{|\nabla g|}}$ to my problem, my issue being the normalization factor. The other thing is that I know for a fact that $\frac{8\pi\rho^2}{3}$ is wrong, since translating the sphere does not change its surface area (and by extension does not change a uniform probability density defined on it).

Comment: In that case you mean the pdf of a normal distribution (distribution in the sense of probability theory), and you can get a consistent definition of the delta function only if you take the distributional limit (distributional in the sense of generalized functions), which is a very roundabout way to define $(\delta, \phi) = \phi(0)$. Are you using the identity from Edit 2 now or from your last comment? They are incompatible.

Comment: @Maxim I never really used the identity from edit 2 since it's something I came up with and I don't trust it (even though it gives the correct answer in this case I am uncertain whether it generalises to other cases, the first reference would imply that it does). The thing I used for edit 3 is what I specified in my previous answer with $g(r,\theta) = r-2\rho\cos\theta$, you can see that the denominator is simply $|\nabla g|$ in this case. The thing left to prove is what $\,d\sigma$ expands into, and the denominator should cancel for one to get $2\rho^2\sin 2\theta \,d\theta\,d\phi$.

Comment: So you think the formula with the gradient should give the surface area and at the same time the formula without the gradient should give the surface area (instead of $8 \pi \rho^2/3$)? $d\sigma$ is an area element, you do not need generalized functions to compute it. The proper calculation goes like this: (continued)

Comment: $$\int_{\mathbb R^3} \delta(x^2 + y^2 + (z - \rho)^2 - \rho^2)
 \,|\nabla(x^2 + y^2 + (z - \rho)^2 - \rho^2)| \,dx dy dz = \\
2 \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^\infty \delta(r (r - 2 \rho \cos \theta))
 \,2 \sqrt{r^2 + \rho^2 - 2 \rho r \cos \theta} \;r^2 \sin \theta \,dr d\theta.$$
Note that the factor $r$ inside the delta function cannot be ignored and the gradient in spherical coordinates is not $(\partial_r f, \partial_\theta f, \partial_\phi f)$ (which is why your Edit 3 cannot be correct). Now if you evaluate this as an iterated integral, you'll get $4 \pi \rho^2$.

Comment: @Maxim No, I thought that the measures $d\sigma$ and $dA$ were different. Thanks for pointing out that I messed up the gradient in edit 3. What bothers me though is that you're computing $\int_{R^3}{\delta(f(x))|\nabla f(x)|dx}$ which is not $\int_{R^3}{\delta(f(x))dx}$. Also could you clarify why I cannot get rid of the $r$? $r(\theta) = 2\rho\cos\theta$ clearly describes the sphere I want. If I integrate it (as a surface) I get precisely what I would expect. I am also unsure how you evaluated the integral, as the substitution leaves me with $4\rho^2r\cos\theta\sin\theta$ as integrand.

Comment: If you take a different measure, you'll get a different answer, which will not be the surface area. Ditto if you drop the gradient. Ditto if you drop $r$. The inner integral is
$$\int_0^\infty \delta(r (r - 2 \rho \cos \theta)) \phi(r) dr =
\frac {\phi(r)} {\left| \frac d {dr} (r (r - 2 \rho \cos \theta)) \right|}
 \bigg\rvert_{r = 2 \rho \cos \theta}$$
(the contribution from the zero at $r = 0$ is zero because of $r^2$ in the Jacobian).

Comment: @Maxim Is $\phi(r) = r^2\sin\theta|\nabla (r(r-2\rho\cos\theta))|$? Where did you get the denominator from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out why I am getting a 'wrong' result. As expected I cannot substitute with the delta directly since it's a composition with a submersion. However the following equality holds from the coarea formula:
$$\int_{R^n}{f(x)\delta(g(x))\,dx} = \int_{g^{-1}(0)}{\frac{f(x)}{|\nabla g(x)|}\,d\sigma(x)}$$
Where $g:R^n\rightarrow R$, $|\nabla g(x)|\ne 0$, and $d\sigma$ is the measure on the surface $g^{-1}(0)$.
Let us consider the non-normalized uniform probability density function on the sphere with center $(0,0,0)$ and radius $\rho$ in spherical coordinates: $p_A(x,y,z) = \delta(r-\rho)r^2\sin\theta$. Unsurprisingly integrating it yields $4\pi\rho^2$:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\delta(r-\rho)r^2\sin\theta\,dr}\,d\theta}\,d\phi} = \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\rho^2\sin\theta}{1}\,d\theta}\,d\phi} = 4\pi\rho^2$$

Note that the division by $1$ is to emphasize that $|\nabla g| = 1$. That is, I have used the coarea formula above even if it may seem unnecessary (but as we'll see later it is actually important for other mappings, and this is simply a special case where we have the standard delta function). Now let us compute the area of the translated sphere. Going to Cartesian coordinates gives us: $p_B(x,y,z) = \frac{p_A(r,\theta)}{|r^2\sin\theta|} = \delta(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-\rho)$ (we have used the invertible pdf transformation theorem). Translating by $(0,0,\rho)$ yields: $p_C(x,y,z) = p_B(x,y,z-\rho)$, where the Jacobian of this transformation is $1$. Finally going back to spherical coordinates we have: 
$$p_D(r,\theta) = \delta(\sqrt{r^2\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta + r^2\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta + r^2\cos\theta^2 + \rho^2 - 2r\rho\cos\theta}-\rho)r^2\sin\theta = \\ 
= \delta(\sqrt{r^2+\rho^2-2r\rho\cos\theta}-\rho)r^2\sin\theta$$
We compute the gradient of the mapping as: $\nabla g(r,\theta) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{r^2+\rho^2-2\rho\cos\theta}}(2r-2\rho\cos\theta, 2\frac{r}{r}\sin\theta,0)$. Finally $|\nabla g(r,\theta)| = 1$. We may compute $g^{-1}(0) = \{(2\rho\cos\theta, \theta, \phi),\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}], \phi \in [0,2\pi]\}$. The surface area element is $dA = 2\rho^2\sin2\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$. Then finally:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{p_D(r,\theta)\,dr}\,d\theta}\,d\phi}
= \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\rho^2\sin2\theta\,d2\theta}\,d\phi} = 4\pi\rho^2$$

Now let us consider a slightly different variant: $p_A(r) = \delta(r^2 - \rho^2)r^2\sin\theta$, $|\nabla g(r)| = 2r$
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\delta(r^2-\rho^2)r^2\sin\theta\,dr}\,d\theta}\,d\phi} = \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\rho^2\sin\theta}{2\rho}\,d\theta}\,d\phi} = 2\pi\rho$$

Rather surprisingly (at least for me) we get a different result, which however for the $\delta$ defined as is, is supposedly correct (I believe that the result being $2\pi\rho$ is just a lucky coincidence). So one has to be careful about the mapping.

After transforming to cartesian coordinates, translating and returning to spherical coordinates we get $p_D(r, \theta) = \delta(r^2-2\rho\cos\theta)r^2\sin\theta$, $|\nabla g(r,\theta)| = 2\sqrt{r^2+\rho^2-2r\rho\cos\theta}$. Using the coarea formula once again:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{p_D(r,\theta)\,dr}\,d\theta}\,d\phi}
= \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\rho^2\sin2\theta}{2\sqrt{\rho^2}}\,d2\theta}\,d\phi} = 2\pi\rho$$

In conclusion, it seems that it is not correct to substitute directly when the delta function is composed with a function different than the identity (or $\pm const$). In that specific case the coarea formula has to be used. Additionally we seem to have the relationship $\delta_S(x) = \delta(g(x))|\nabla g(x)|$, where $S=g^{-1}(0)$:

$$\int_{R^n}{f(x)\delta(g(x))|\nabla g(x)|\,dx} = \int_{R^n}{f(x)\delta_S(x)\,dx} = \int_{S}{f(x)\,d\sigma(x)}$$

I very much appreciate the input from Maxim and David Holden, which ultimately helped me figure this out.

Edit: A very interesting read I found later: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath663/kmath663.htm
It certainly helps to understand the problem from an intuitive point of view also.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the discussion in the comments, the definition of $\delta(f)$ is derived from postulating two basic properties: the substitution rule
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(f(\mathbf x)) \,\phi(\mathbf x) \,d\mathbf x =
\int_U \delta(f(\mathbf x(\mathbf u))) \,\phi(\mathbf x(\mathbf u))
 \left| \det D \mathbf x(\mathbf u) \right| d\mathbf u$$
and
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(x_1) \,\phi(\mathbf x) \,d\mathbf x =
\int_{\mathbb R^{n - 1}} \phi(\mathbf x) \rvert_{x_1 = 0} \,dx_2 \cdots dx_n.$$
If you try to set
$$\small \int \delta(f(\mathbf x)) d\mathbf x =
\int_{f(\mathbf x) = 0} dS =
\int_{2 f(\mathbf x) = 0} dS =
\int \delta(2 f(\mathbf x)) d\mathbf x,$$
you violate the first rule. If you try to set
$$\small \iint \delta(r - f(\theta)) \phi(r, \theta) dr d\theta \neq
\int \phi(f(\theta), \theta) d\theta,$$
you violate the second rule. If you adopt the definition <s>that the rest of the world is using</s> derived from the two stated properties, you get the identity
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(f(\mathbf x))
 \left| \nabla f(\mathbf x) \right| \phi(\mathbf x) \,d\mathbf x =
\int_{f(\mathbf x) = 0} \phi(\mathbf x) \,dS(\mathbf x),$$
which is formally the same as the [coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) because both are essentially the same change of variables formula. The first two formulas in your question will in fact be correct, while the last two will be incorrect.

Comment: There are some small details, like the coarea formula being more general than the substitution. I think Federer developed it not so long ago too either. But for the problem at hand both work equally well. Thank you for all of the input. After I figured everything out, I found many references of this in physics books, so it certainly helps  asking the right question.

Comment: Also what first two formulae are you referring to? The second equality in my question is wrong. All the equalities in my answer should be correct however. @Maxim

Comment: I refer to the formulas $\iiint = 4 \pi \rho^2$ and $\iiint = 8 \pi \rho^2/3$. If you still insist that the second one is wrong, then we haven't made any progress. I specifically tried to explain above why insisting that it should give some other answer is incompatible with the formula you're trying to derive.

Comment: I am not sure how you managed to integrate that thing. Using the coarea formula the second formula gives you $|\nabla f| = \sqrt{1 + 4\rho^2\sin^2\theta / r^2}$ in the denominator. And $2\rho\sin2\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$ in the numerator with integration limits $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$ and $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$. My issue is really that $r^2$ in the denominator. I am assuming it's supposed to be $r = 2\rho\cos\theta$. But even then I don't think you'll get $8\pi\rho^2/3$.

Comment: First, $dS = 2 \rho^2 \sin 2 \theta \,d\theta d\phi$. Then
$$2 \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac
 {2 \rho^2 \sin 2 \theta}
 {\sqrt{1 + \frac {4 \rho^2 \sin^2 \theta} {r^2}}}
  \bigg\rvert_{r = 2 \rho \cos \theta} \,d\theta =
\frac {8 \pi \rho^2} 3.$$
But this exercise is completely pointless if you ignore the reason why
$$2 \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^\infty
 \delta(r - 2 \rho \cos \theta) \,r^2 \sin \theta \,dr d\theta =
2 \pi \int_0^{\pi/2} r^2 \sin \theta \rvert_{r = 2 \rho \cos \theta} \,d\theta$$
gives the same result.

Comment: Oh it does in fact match, guess I integrated wrong. This is just a coincidence though I guess because of the form of the submersion. In the general case this will not work I take it. So it turns out that with $r-2\rho\cos\theta$ I was modeling the wrong problem indeed, since even though if it describes the surface of a translated sphere, the parametrisation matters. If I had $\delta_S(r,\theta)$ it would have modelled the 'correct' problem. Thank you for all the comments on this.

Comment: And I do realize that the last 2 equations in my question are incorrect that's why I fixed them in the answer, I left them in the question just so that it would be obvious where my confusion stems from. It seems like I really wanted to use $\delta_S$ the whole time rather than $\delta$, I just didn't know the relationship between the two previously. And as you mentioned the coarea formula seems to be unnecessary for the smooth case, where a substitution yields the desired result.

Comment: What are the hypotheses on the function $f$? and the set $U$? in the substitution rule?

Comment: @pre-kidney The usual conditions required to make the corresponding real analysis theorems hold. $\mathbf u \to \mathbf x(\mathbf u): U \to \mathbb R^n$ is bijective with non-zero jacobian, $\nabla f$ is non-zero.

Comment: The case when $x$ is bijective is not too interesting, since the zero set is a single point (and does not apply in recent posts we are discussing that link to here). Also, you neglected to state hypotheses on $U$ - is it assumed to be an open set?

Comment: @pre-kidney It has to be bijective: injective for the u-substitution theorem to hold and surjective to give all of $\mathbb R^n$. That part has nothing to do with zero-dimensional sets. The point is that from those two properties we can derive the last formula (by choosing local coordinates where $f$ is one of the coordinates in a small neighborhood of a point on $f = 0$, then applying the change of variables, then the sifting property).

Comment: Right, but my point is that this formula cannot be used to *define* quantities like $\delta(g)$ when $g$ is non-bijective, as (I thought) you had suggested in the discussion on the post linking to here.

Comment: @pre-kidney $\mathbf u \to \mathbf x(\mathbf u)$ is bijective. $g$ (called $f$ here) is $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, obviously we do not require it to be bijective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95539/discussion-between-pre-kidney-and-maxim).

Answer (score 1):

when you write *integrating yields...* you may be making an unwarranted assumption about what is the "element of area". a simple geometric approach suggests:

$$
dA = \rho d(2\theta) \rho \sin 2\theta d\phi = 2 \rho^2 \sin 2\theta d\theta d\phi
$$

note that with $dA$ thus defined:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} dA = 4\pi\rho^2 
$$

Comment: I am not changing the parametrisation nor am I integrating over area though. I know very well how to compute the area as a surface integral. My point is that I want the factors to pop out from the Dirac delta's change. Basically I want this explained in terms of the Dirac delta and what am I doing wrong with it (in the general case not only for sphere). I've seen a property in 1D where the absolute value of derivative pops out of the Dirac delta when applying a transformation $\delta(f(x))$. I would like the multidimensional case, preferably with an example applied to my problem.